# How can it be that the back-end code for a website is C++ and front-end is PHP?

Tags: php, c++, apache, webserver

I asked a Facebook engineer what main programming language they use for development. He specifically said "we use C++ for back-end stuff, and PHP for front-end stuff". This doesn't really make any sense to me. I initially translated this to mean 'server-side' code is C++ and 'client-side' is PHP, but after researching this link:
http://tinsology.net/2009/06/client-side-vs-server-side-code/
It seems that PHP is in fact server-side code, and HTML/CSS are client-side. Moreover, C++ is not generally used on a webserver running Apache or IIS. Any ideas what he meant?

Comment: Facebook developed a tool that converts PHP to C++, to reduce their number of servers and energy consumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ *can* be used for CGI's, but I think you misunderstood. They will probably use PHP for the websites, and C++ for backoffice applications and/or webservices. The website is the 'front-end' of the business, so PHP is back-end or front-end, depending on your point of view. 
PHP is indeed a server side scripting language, so if you're a web developer and you look at it from a web developer's view, PHP indeed is back-end.

Comment: Thank you your response, it surely answered my question. I am not sure why the community deemed this question not constructive though.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook writes (nearly) all of their code in PHP, but they use a compiler to convert it to C++ code.

This is because there are way more PHP programmers than C++ programmers on this world, but C++ is way faster and more efficient.

Answer (score -1):

PHP for things like user login, keeping track of posts etc. and they use C++ for things like databases and obv. the back end.

C++ isn't really uses - you're right. It's just that C++ is faster and with millions of lines of code a small increase in speed here and there adds up. As it runs faster, it also has a lighter load on the servers, saving money and electricity.

I suggest you look at a program called "HIpHOp" which transforms PHP into C++. It was actually written by Facebook engineers for Facebook itself and I'm sure the released it to the public.